# client.guilds.each does not appear to be a function [Discord.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Okay, I'm making a discord TTS bot. I get this error stating that message.guild.each is not a function.

The code is :

```
  **client.guilds.each((guild) => {
    guild.ttsPlayer = new TTSPlayer(guild);
  });
};**
```

Log dump from console.log:

```
 GuildManager {
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066042+00:00 app[worker.1]:   cacheType: [Function: Collection],
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066064+00:00 app[worker.1]:   cache: Collection [Map] {
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066064+00:00 app[worker.1]:     '653281212751806494' => TTSGuild {
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066065+00:00 app[worker.1]:       members: [GuildMemberManager],
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066065+00:00 app[worker.1]:       channels: [GuildChannelManager],
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066066+00:00 app[worker.1]:       roles: [RoleManager],
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066066+00:00 app[worker.1]:       presences: [PresenceManager],
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066067+00:00 app[worker.1]:       voiceStates: [VoiceStateManager],
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066067+00:00 app[worker.1]:       deleted: false,
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066068+00:00 app[worker.1]:       available: true,
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066068+00:00 app[worker.1]:       id: '653281212751806494',
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066068+00:00 app[worker.1]:       shardID: 0,
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066068+00:00 app[worker.1]:       ttsPlayer: null,
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066069+00:00 app[worker.1]:       name: 'some pokemon plays',
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066069+00:00 app[worker.1]:       icon: '6eb6adbaf0333ab25f654c5a186aad9d',
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066069+00:00 app[worker.1]:       splash: null,
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066070+00:00 app[worker.1]:       region: 'europe',
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066070+00:00 app[worker.1]:       memberCount: 8,
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066070+00:00 app[worker.1]:       large: false,
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066071+00:00 app[worker.1]:       features: [],
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066071+00:00 app[worker.1]:       applicationID: null,
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066071+00:00 app[worker.1]:       afkTimeout: 300,
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066071+00:00 app[worker.1]:       afkChannelID: null,
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066072+00:00 app[worker.1]:       systemChannelID: '653281212751806497',
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066072+00:00 app[worker.1]:       embedEnabled: undefined,
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066072+00:00 app[worker.1]:       premiumTier: 0,
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066073+00:00 app[worker.1]:       premiumSubscriptionCount: 0,
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066073+00:00 app[worker.1]:       verificationLevel: 'NONE',
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066074+00:00 app[worker.1]:       explicitContentFilter: 'DISABLED',
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066074+00:00 app[worker.1]:       mfaLevel: 0,
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066074+00:00 app[worker.1]:       joinedTimestamp: 1575958233113,
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066075+00:00 app[worker.1]:       defaultMessageNotifications: 'ALL',
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066075+00:00 app[worker.1]:       systemChannelFlags: [SystemChannelFlags],
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066075+00:00 app[worker.1]:       vanityURLCode: null,
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066076+00:00 app[worker.1]:       description: null,
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066076+00:00 app[worker.1]:       banner: null,
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066076+00:00 app[worker.1]:       rulesChannelID: null,
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066077+00:00 app[worker.1]:       publicUpdatesChannelID: null,
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066077+00:00 app[worker.1]:       ownerID: '376363119632580622',
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066078+00:00 app[worker.1]:       emojis: [GuildEmojiManager]
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066078+00:00 app[worker.1]:     }
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066079+00:00 app[worker.1]:   }
2020-03-04T23:39:31.066079+00:00 app[worker.1]: }
```

The console log is given above.

Can someone enlighten me as to why that is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
client.guilds.each((guild) => {
    guild.ttsPlayer = new TTSPlayer(guild);
  });
```

to

```
client.guilds.forEach((guild) => {
    guild.ttsPlayer = new TTSPlayer(guild);
  });
```

**Edit:** your guilds is an object, you use `for...in` for object

```
for (const prop in client.guilds) {
  console.log(`client.guilds.${prop} = ${client.guilds[prop]}`);
}
```

Comment: Still have the same problem. client.guilds.forEach is not recognized as a function

Comment: can you log your client.guilds and see what is coming in it use `console.log(client.guilds)`

Comment: Console.log output is added to the question.

Comment: @GeekWorks, is that your client.guilds log

Answer (score 0):

You could get some clues by looking into the documentation https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds